# Storing object in BinarySearchTree leads to weird dereference problems

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

For an assignment I need to write code that takes a string as input and counts what word is the most used in that string.

We need to implement this using a Binary Search Tree of a structure called "WordCount" that contains a character array and the count of how many times the word appears.

This is how the structure is defined.

```
struct wordcount {
    char word[80];
    int count;
};

typedef struct wordcount WordCount;
```

A binary search tree must have a way to create nodes, this is the code:

```
BSTnode* createNode(void* item) {
    BSTnode* newNode = (BSTnode*) malloc(sizeof(BSTnode));

    newNode->item = item;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode; 
}
```

When I store the WordCount structure inside of the Binary Search Tree and attempt to access the item, and then access the word, I get a Segmentation Fault.

If I just try to access the item of the tree, I get the char word array. This doesn't make sense because I'm storing the wordCount structure, so I should have to dereference it twice.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc >= 1) {
        WordCount* firstWord = (WordCount*) malloc(sizeof(WordCount));
        strcpy(firstWord->word,argv[1]);
        firstWord->count = 0;
        BSTnode* BST = createNode(firstWord);
        printf("%s", BST->item); // should be BST->item->word...but this does not work and says that it cannot find "word" which is apart of 
    }
    /*int i;
    char string[80];
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        sscanf(argv[i], "%s", string);
        //printf("%s ", string);
        //insert(main, argv[i], wordCountCompare);
    }*/
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if my explanation was entirely vague or incomplete or if I'm overlooking something entirely.

I also want to clarify that the printf statements are merely for debugging only they won't be apart of the actual program...however the point still stands.

Definition of BSTnode:

```
struct bstnode {
    void *item;
    struct bstnode *left;
    struct bstnode *right;
};
typedef struct bstnode BSTnode;
```

Comment: Is should be `printf("%s", BST->item.word)`.

Comment: `item` is a pointer. Shouldn't it be `BST->item->word`?

Comment: says that word is not apart of the structure or union, again which is odd, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: BST->item->word also gives me the same thing

Comment: Please show the definition of `BSTNode`

Comment: Updated to show BSTnode.

Comment: Please show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *item* should be of wordcount type.

```
struct bstnode {
    wordcount *item;
    struct bstnode *left;
    struct bstnode *right;
};
typedef struct bstnode BSTnode;
```

You can't be dereferencing void pointers (which lead to the compilation error)

Comment: I solved the question after I left but this is the (kinda) the correct answer. What I did instead was just cast ((WordCount*)BST->item)->word like this. That way if we wanted to create a bstnode of int's or other types we can.

Definitely should have read the warnings...

Answer (score 0):

You're likely getting these errors because you're trying to dereference a pointer to NULL. Learn how to use the debugger!. Hint: break in main and step thru the function to see where the segmentation fault occurs

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: @micheal touché. Next time!

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%s", BST->item);
```

Printf's "%s" expects a string, and `item` is a structure. Try:

```
printf("%s" BST->item->word);
```